# echo unsigned 64 bit variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hex, xor

I have the following shell code:

```
Val1=0123456789abcdef
Val2=fedcba9876543210

Val3_dec=$((16#$Val1 ^ 16#$Val2))
Val3=`echo "obase=16; $Val3_dec" | bc`
echo $Val1
echo $Val2
echo $Val3_dec 
echo $Val3
```

with the corresponding output:

```
0123456789abcdef
fedcba9876543210
-1
-1
```

unfortunately the output of Val3 is signed negative, but I need it to be a 64 bit unsigned output in HEX.
Like:

```
0123456789abcdef
fedcba9876543210
-1    (the output of Val3_dec does not matter)
ffffffffffffffff
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use printf:

```
#!/bin/bash
Val1=0123456789abcdef
Val2=fedcba9876543210

Val3_dec=$((16#$Val1 ^ 16#$Val2))
Val3=`echo "obase=16; $Val3_dec" | bc`
echo $Val1
echo $Val2
printf "%d\n" $Val3_dec 
printf "%x\n" $Val3
```

Results:

```
$ ./test.sh 
0123456789abcdef
fedcba9876543210
-1
ffffffffffffffff
```